# Magento2 apache rewrites not working on local

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

I have a new local version of Magento2 and it all works and installs correctly.

The only thing that isn't working is the URL rewrites. I have an htaccess file in the root of the site.

Apache 2.4 - attached is my vhost file. (Maybe I need something else here?)

Mac El Capitan

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /Users/brent/Sites/magento2/
        ServerName magento2.super-awesome-test.com
        <Directory  /Users/brent/Sites/magento2>
        Require all granted
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /Users/brent/Sites/magento2/logs/mage2-error.log
        CustomLog /Users/brent/Sites/magento2/logs/mage2-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have module rewrite enabled in Apache?

Comment: The command is `a2enmod rewrite` and you probably need to run it as root.

Comment: @SteveJohnson isn't a2enmod for Ubuntu?

Comment: I believe a2enmod is for Apache 2.4. If you can get Apache 2.4 to work on CentOS, I expect you'd have to set it.

Comment: I had mod_rewrite enabled, and adding the <Directory> in the vhost record worked for me - thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was when I upgraded to El Capitan it overwrote my existing httpd.conf file and the mod_rewrite was commented out.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

I uncommented it and Mod_Rewrite works!